# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: x509certificate2, xero-api

I followed the instructions at [the Xero developer network](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/create-publicprivate-key) to set up my Win 64 public and private key, and registered a demo app.

I am using the code at the API [.net framework 4 source](https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Net)`

When I try and run a unit test from the CoreTest project it fails.

I edited the CoreTests\App.Config to use the values from my registered app with

```
<add key="SigningCertificate" value="C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\public_privatekey.pfx"/>
```

When I run a test I get the error

[image]

I am wondering do I need to register the .pfx somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I had actually forgotten to take the last step to construct the .pfx

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out public_privatekey.pfx -inkey privatekey.pem -in publickey.cer
```